# How to add a custom HTML to a perticular page in wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress

Here I am adding CSS property in additional CSS in particular page. But it is affecting other pages also. How to do that. I am using content view plugin. I want to add a classname in HTML file in one of the WordPress page. Please tell me how that can be done.

Comment: To stop affecting other elements why not use a unique class name?

Comment: How to add a unique class name in a perticular page?

Answer (score 0):

apply CSS using parent class like

Eg
your page name is : test-data

Then CSS should be

body.page-test-data h1{
/* Your css */
}

Comment: This method is not ideal if the css for the page is going to be a lot. Leaves open for many possible css mistakes

Answer (score 0):

You can add an id to the tag :

```
<!-- HTML --> 
<div id="myID"></div>
```

Then in your css file you can use your id:

```
#myId { /* My style */ }
```

Or you can create a new css file and add it to the specific page

Comment: where shall I add this div? in which file?

Comment: On the element you want to display. If your text is writting in Pages, you can open code-view to edit it.